# Syntax error: Encountered "t" at line 1, column 54

Tags: database, netbeans, syntax, arraylist

I'm getting an error that says "Syntax error: Encountered "t" at line 1, column 54"

This only seems to happen when the enhanced for loop for the History list iterates more than once. It works perfectly fine when I add one row of items, but when I add any more it gives me this error

Here is my code:

```
public void databaseSave( ArrayList <Patient> pList )
{

    try
    {
        stmt = getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        //Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        //Deletes all records from the Patient Table.
        deleteAllFromPatientTable();

        //Selects all the records from the Patient table.
        selectAllFromPatient();


        System.out.println("Before loop");

        for ( Patient p: pList )
        {

            patientInsertSQL = "Insert Into SHAUN.PATIENT VALUES (" + p.getPatientNum() + ", '"
            + p.getPatientName() + "', '" + p.getPatientAddress() + "', '"
            + p.getPatientPhone() + "')";

            res = stmt.executeUpdate(patientInsertSQL); 

            System.out.println(res);


            ArrayList <History> tempHistList = p.getHistory();

            //Deletes all the records from the history table.
            deleteAllFromHistoryTable();

            //Selects all the records from the history table.
            selectAllFromHistory();

            for ( History h: tempHistList )
            {                   
                historyInsertSQL = "Insert Into SHAUN.HISTORY VALUES (" + h.getHistID() + ", '" + h.getConditionName() + "', '" + h.getMedication() + "', '" + h.getDateOccured() + "', " + p.getPatientNum() + ")";

                res = stmt.executeUpdate(historyInsertSQL); 

                System.out.println(res);

                //Loop Checker
                int i = 1;
                System.out.println("In the History Loop " + i);
                i++;
            }

            System.out.println("In the loop!");

        }

        stmt.close();
        result.close();
        con.commit();

        System.out.println("After Loop and close");

    }
    catch (SQLException err)
    {
        System.out.print(err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: SLaks is right. Be sure to sanitize your user input(or any input for that matter) before using it in a sql command.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got an SQL injection problem, and the `t` mentioned in your error is coming from something like

```
INSERT INTO .....'Can't Tolerate X'
                     ^---
```

Comment: That ended up being the problem... I had the word 'Don't' in there. I never would have thought that was the problem.

Comment: SQL injection. Better read up and learn how to avoid it, before you do anything else with this code: http://bobby-tables.com